# A way to add space between two unicode characters

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am using R to do an analysis of tweets and would like to include emojis in my analysis. I have read useful resources and consulted the emoji dictionaries from from both Jessica Peterka Bonetta and Kate Lyons. However, I am running into a problem when there are emojis right next to each other in tweets.

For example, if a use a Tweet with multiple emojis that are spread out, I will get the results I am looking for:

```
x <- iconv(x, from = "UTF8", to = "ASCII", sub = "byte")
x
```

x will return:

> "Ummmm our plane <9c><88><8f> got delayed <9a><8f> and I<80><99>m kinda nervous <9f><98><96> but I<80><99>m on my way <9c><85> home <9f><8f> so that<80><99>s really exciting <80><8f> t<80>

Which when matching with Kate Lyons' emoji dictionary:

```
FindReplace(data = x, Var = "x", replaceData = emoticons, from="R_Encoding", to = "Name", exact = FALSE)
```

Will yield:

> Ummmm our plane  AIRPLANE  got delayed  WARNINGSIGN  and I<80><99>m kinda nervous <9f><98><96> but I<80><99>m on my way  WHITEHEAVYCHECKMARK  home <9f><8f> so that<80><99>s really exciting  DOUBLEEXCLAMATIONMARK  t<80>

If there is a tweet with two emojis in a row, such as:

> "Delayed\U0001f615\U0001f615\n.\n.\n.\n\n#flying #flight #travel #delayed #baltimore #january #flightdelay #travelproblems #bummer… "

Repeating the process with iconv from above will not work, because it will not match the codings in the emoji dictionary. Therefore, I thought of adding a space between the two patterns(\U0001f615\U0001f615) to become 
(\U0001f615 \U0001f615), however I am struggling with a proper regular expression for this.

Comment: `gsub("\\", "\\ ", Tweets)` ?

Comment: How is the string printed on the console? Like this: "\U0001f615\U0001f615"?

Comment: Try `gsub("([\U{1F300}-\U{1F6FF}])(?=[\U{1F300}-\U{1F6FF}])", "\\1 ", x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Did it work for you? [It works here](https://ideone.com/mRuUal)

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew, it did work. Thank you! Unfortunately, the encodings for repeated emojis still do not match those found in the emoji dictionary. I'll have to find another work through.

Comment: I can share a regex to match any emoji, but it is really large. Can you share a list of the emojis supported by the package you are using?